# Extended Stored Procedure with ODBC DSN

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, odbc, dsn

I have an extended stored procedure (written in Delphi if that makes any difference) that makes its own connection via ODBC and performs some processing - stuff that can't be done using T-SQL alone.

If I try to connect using the System DSN that is set up (e.g. named MyDataSource), the xp returns the following error:

*[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server] Cannot open database requested in login 'MyDataSource'. Login fails.*

However, if I connect using a connection string (SERVER=MyServerName;DATABASE=MyDatabaseName;etc) then it connects & the xp works.

I tested the code outside of an xp, just a Windows app, and the connection using the DSN worked. I'd expect this as it is the same way I have connected to a database for 10 years!

So I have it working but really want to know why it doesn't work using a DSN. I also tried with a user DSN but no difference.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: The latest is that this simply does not work on SQL Server 2000. On SQL Server 2008, this does work but I've no idea which database my xp is connecting to. It certainly isn't the one that the ODBC DSN points to, nor is it the default database for the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that when the extended stored procedure is executed it is running under the login that the SQL server service is using. If the log in that SQL server does not have permissions on the network then denial errors will occur. I hope this helps.

Comment: OK thank you, that might be useful. The user is actually an SQL Server user, not a Windows user. I can understand this might affect things if the ODBC DSN was a User DSN, but it is a System DSN and it is all taking place on the same server.

Comment: Seeing as you were the only one to answer, even though it didn't help, I'll accept this. Thanks.